# Yahtzee, need two arguments to an if, remove method

Tags: python-3.x

So I'm trying to make yahtzee-board, but I've come to an obstacle which shouldn't be that hard to solve, but I simply cant fix it. This is how my remove function is looking currently:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
        self.lista={"aces":0,"twos":0,"threes":0,"fours":0,"fives":0,"sixs":0,"upperscore":0,"bonus":0,"pair":0,"twopair":0,"3ofakind":0,"4ofakind":0,"smallstraight":0,"largestraight":0,"fullhouse":0,"chance":0,"yahtzee":0,"lowerscore":0,"totalscore":0}
        self.upperbracket={"aces":0,"twos":0,"threes":0,"fours":0,"fives":0,"sixs":0}
        self.lowerbracket={"pair":0,"twopair":0,"3ofakind":0,"4ofakind":0,"smallstraight":0,"largestraight":0,"fullhouse":0,"chance":0,"yahtzee":0}

    def remove(self,i):
        b=input("Do you want to remove a moment?:")
        if b=="yes":
            c=input("Which moment do you want to remove?")
            spelarlista[i].lista[c]=str("&")
            self.printtable()
            return True
        if b=="no":
            return False

    def add(self):
        rundor=0
        while rundor!=15:
            for i in range(len(spelarlista)):
                count=0
                print("Rolling dice for: ", str(spelarlista[i]))
                self.rolldice()
                if self.remove(i)==True:
                    i=i+1
                    count+=1
                while count<=0:
                    moment=input("Where do you want to put your points,"+" "+ str(spelarlista[i])+"?:""\n" )
                    while moment not in self.lista:
                        print("oops! Try again!")
                    if spelarlista[i].lista[moment]!=0 or spelarlista[i].lista[moment]==str("&"):
                        print("Moment has either been removed or you already got points there")
                    else:
                        points=input("How many points did you get?: ")
```

What I want to do is that if I decide to remove an already removed "moment" it's supposed to print "no can do" or something like that, the same thing is if there is already points there.

currently the line of code is looking like this:

```
if spelarlista[i].lista[moment]!=0 or spelarlista[i].lista[moment]==str("&"):
```

Notice that this line is working prefectly if I've already added points, but if I try to remove an already removed "moment" it does not work as intended, I simply cant see where everything has gone wrong...

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work as intended"? What do you intend, and what does it do? Your code can't be run as listed.  You should also let us know what the `spelarlista` and `lista` arrays contain. Note str("&") is exactly the same as "&", since it is already a string.

Comment: spelarlista is simply a list with all my playernames, lista is a dictionary with my "moments", that is "aces","twos"; threes", "chance" etc,. What I intend to do with it, is that if there is a "&" inside the board, its supposed to print
"No, you cant put points there" or something like that

Comment: Can you create a complete and verifiable example. Create a new file with a example of what the lista dictionary is like, and complete code including your remove function and the conditional,  that I can copy, paste and run to see the problem.

Comment: I did an update now, hopefully its easier to see the problem

Comment: One thing I would suggest is that you keep your game logic and your user interface separate. So your player class should not contain any kind of text interface for the user to interact with - only game logic. Write your ui separately then if later you want to make a graphical interface, or a web interface or have a mobile app front end - well you can go ahead and do that with minimal effort.

Comment: I still get NameErrors, `spelarlist` is not defined, nor is `rolldice`, perhaps you could put some dummy code in, that would let someone run this. Also tell us exactly what we have type into the various inputs in order to get the error that you have.

Comment: you guys are right, Im unsure how to fix this "dummy" code without putting everything up...